# sharepoint products configuration wizard - Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have just installed SharePoint Server 2010 on a Windows 7 machine, and every time i try to confogire it, i get an Unhandled exception. Reproduction steps are as follows -- Install Sharepoint 2010 (Server Farm or standalone instance, i've tried both) -- Run the configuration wizard -- Click Ok to the messageboxs (Warning about installing on Win 7 machine, and another about the wizard restarting certain services).

and then i get the unhandled exception.

EDIT----
the exception i get is "Version string portion is too short or too long"

and im installing on Windows Server 2008 R2

Any ideas?

Comment: "Unhanded Exception" - why yes, I know exactly what the problem is there ;)

Comment: Did you have a look in the logs?

Comment: @Ryan - Sarcasm is always helpful

Comment: come on! What did you expect? Zero information to troubleshoot with is about as helpful as sarcasm but less funny ;) You did notice the link I also provided with troubleshooting steps and details of how to get the logs didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

This may help - at least will show you where the log files are to get more details

[10 Tips Troubleshooting Installations for SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Foundation](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d-183c-4fc2-8320-ba5369008acb&ID=280)